# How to convert interface[] to List<implementation> in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, interface

I have an interface say Foo

```
interface Foo {
}
```

and an implementation say FooImpl

```
class FooImpl implements Foo {
}
```

My requirement is to convert `Foo[]` to `ArrayList<FooImpl>`

Anyone have a quick solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by Foo[] ?

Comment: an array of Foo interface

Comment: Why do you need `ArrayList<FooImpl>` and not `List<Foo>`?

Comment: For convenience of use

Comment: No. Not duplicate. Please read the question carefully, I am asking to convert to a list of implementation class, not the same class/interface ("Element" in the other thread of Stackoverflow)